# UIButton not showing my UIbuttons background images for Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, nsarray

[image: The Dice is a button and when you touch it it rolles the dice and show the result on the dice button]. So it will show the image of random 1-6 image of the dice on the button by touching the UIButton with a IBAction using a array and a random() to select from the array of images to desplay on the image background

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)diceButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    _diceArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dice_1.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dice_2.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dice_3.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dice_4.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dice_5.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dice_6.png"],nil];

    int index = random() % 5 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < [_diceArray count]; i++) {
        [_diceButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[_diceArray objectAtIndex:index]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
@end
```

Comment: what you trying to do?

Comment: you already store the image in the array not the name in the array. so  di like this [_diceButton setBackgroundImage:[_diceArray objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
[_diceButton setBackgroundImage:_diceArray[index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Since your `_diceArray` contains `UIImage`'s not image names

Answer (score 1):

> hi you have two way to correct this program, first one change your
>   array **to**

```
_diceArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"Dice_1.png",
                           @"Dice_2.png",
                           @"Dice_3.png",
                           @"Dice_4.png",
                           @"Dice_5.png",
                           @"Dice_6.png",nil];
```

> **or**  change

```
[_diceButton setBackgroundImage:[_diceArray objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing `UIImage` objects in the array so you can't call

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[_diceArray objectAtIndex:index]
```

So you need to use:

```
[_diceButton setBackgroundImage:[_diceArray objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

**My Suggestion :** use `setImage:` instead of `setBackgroundImage:`

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_diceArray count]; i++)
{
   [_diceButton setImage:[_diceArray objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [_diceButton setImage:[_diceArray objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```